# MongoDB $elemMatch issue

Tags: mongodb

I'm fairly new to MongoDB and I think I'm misunderstanding how $elemMatch works. I'm running the below two queries which I would expect to return identical result sets. The first one returns what I would expect, all documents that have an element stats.o equal to one. The second query doesn't return any documents. Does anyone know why I would be getting results with the first query but not the second? The database is running on MongoLab which is running MongoDB 2.2.

```
{
    "stats.o":1
}


{
    "stats": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "o": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the structure of the document?

Comment: Is stats an array or a document?  $elemMatch only works on an array...

Answer (score 0):

You are likely seeing the effects of $elemMatch only being applicable to arrays of embedded documents, not simple embedded documents.

There is a request to extend functionality of $elemMatch tracked as https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6050

So if your document is:

`{ stat : { o : 1 } }`

you cannot use $elemMatch (but then you don't really need to).

But if it's

`{ stat : [ { o : 1 } ] }`

then you can and may actually need to use $elemMatch to get the correct results (in situations where you have many array elements and multiple criteria that must be matched "together".